# python run as administrator interrupt wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, runas

I am developing a script that uses admin privilege I use the code beneath to acquire it, but when I add it to my script, suddenly the wxpython won't show.

What should I do to fix it?

```
    # Enable Adminstrator Privelaged
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'
if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    try:
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    except Exception as e:
        if e[-1]=="The operation was canceled by the user.":
            print "נא לאפשר הרשאות מנהלן לתוכנה"
        else:
            print "שגיאה בהפעלת המנהלן, פרטי השגיאה:\n"+str(e)
    sys.exit(0)


app = wx.App(False)
x=MainGUI(None,app)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this code correctly, it looks like you exit your script if the the user doesn't pass in `asadmin` on the command line. So when you run the script with no parameters or with the wrong string passed in, then your `if` statement runs. When that runs, it calls `sys.exit(0)` at the end, which causes the script to end there.

Thus you never reach the wxPython part of the code.

Comment: yea but it should calls sys.exit(0) because it runs the script again just with administrator privileages

Comment: You should print out the `params` variable. See if that gets printed twice.